# Doubt in a calculation technique

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $2$ men or $3$ women or $4$ boys can do a piece of work in $52$ days, then the same piece of work will be done by $1$ man, $1$ woman and $1$ boy in how many days?

**Doubt:**
Here they have constructed an analogy where they have equated $4B$ with $52$ and $B$ came out to be $52 \cdot 4$ and they claimed the analogy of inversely proportional. I really have no idea why they did it. For me it seems $52/4$.

Comment: If fewer men than boys are needed to do the task in the same time, what does it imply ? Alternatively, use a compound unit, person-days. 4*52 boy-days = 2*52 man-days

Comment: What does right hand side equal to? Why do we always make that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's calculate the amount of work anyone can do in one day.
$$
\text{Men:} \qquad M = \frac{1}{52 \cdot 2} \qquad (\text{"items of work per day"})
$$
$$
\text{Women:} \qquad W = \frac{1}{52 \cdot 3}
$$
$$
\text{Boys:} \qquad B = \frac{1}{52 \cdot 4}
$$
Therefore the combined amount of work that one man, one woman and one boy can make in one day is
$$
M + W + B = \frac{1}{52} \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \right)
 = \frac{1}{48}$$

The amount of time it takes to finish one item of work is the inverse of this number.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What is particularly very alluring to me is to use the concept of efficiency and solve this without fractions. Can you assist me slightly with the same. maybe to solve the question fast I am more reluctant to use the LCM technique.

Comment: To solve without fractions? Do you have a particular reason to do it so? It seems challenging because the calculations very easily require taking the inverses of numbers ... And what does Least Common Multiple have to do with this?

Comment: How can inverse proportion rule be used to solve these problems?

Answer (score 1):

Since you find the concept of efficiency very alluring,
if the boy's efficiency = $100$%, by **inverse proportion**,
woman's efficiency = $\frac43*100$%, and man's is $200$%

Thus time needed = $\dfrac{4*100*52}{(100+\frac43\cdot100+200)}= 48$ days

---

**PS**
The method I was proposing in my comment was that amount of work = 4*52 = 208 *boy-days*, and by inverse proportion, $1$ man-day = $2$ boy-days, $1$ woman-day = $\frac43$ boy-days,

Thus time needed to complete work $=\dfrac{208}{(1+2+ 4/3)} = 48$ days

Comment: What is inverse proportion?

Comment: Generally speaking, direct proportion has the formula $\frac{y}{x} = k$, while inverse proportion has the formula $yx=k$. In the context here, inverse proportion means that as "efficiency" (capability) increases, time needed to do the work decreases.