Complex rates and variation question
Salome, Jeny, Anna and Theresia can eat 2 bags of rice in 12 day. Each bag weighs 10 kg. How many people can eat 6 bags of the same weight in 18 days?
I know it looks simpler but what I need to know more is that, which variable is direct proportional to the other and inverse to other? or should it be done in different way?

Fairly similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4156550/doubt-in-a-calculation-technique/4156673#4156673

I checked it, it is very different indeed.

Let's say that one person can eat $x$ bags of rice in one day. The first statement claims that
$$
4x = \frac{2}{12}
$$
Now we want an expression that gets $\frac{6}{18}= \frac{1}{3} = \frac{4}{12}$ on the other side. So I think you just have to multiply both sides by $2$:
$$
8x = \frac{6}{18}
$$
This of course assumes that everyone can constantly eat the same amount per day, and doesn't get tired of eating, etc.
